# Huge buggy padding in line-number buffer

Tags: spacemacs, line-numbers

A picture:

[image]

As you can see there is a huge waste of space on the left side of the line number section.

When I increase the font size the padding even increases and does not decrease when I decrease the font size back.

I am using the most recent version of spacemacs and the `tsdh-light` theme.

Comment: How about using the built-in (C code base) line numbering mechanism that comes with Emacs 26+?  Any line numbers to the left of the fringe are generated by Lisp code such as `linum.el` or `nlinum.el`, which have been deprecated in favor of the line numbers that are built-in to the C code base as of Emacs 26 -- the line numbers are to the right of the fringe in such a case and the left margin area is reserved for other usages.